# how to pass String including comma in CXF service method

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm using camel cxf component to call web service. I'm trying to pass XML String, which has a comma (,). when I'm trying to pass XML string it throws below error.

**Get the wrong parameter size to invoke the out s
ervice, Expect size 1, Parameter size 2. Please check if the message body matches the CXFEndpoint POJO Dataformat request.**

Here is my web service method

```
public String sendSMSRequest(
    @WebParam(name = "clientRequestXML", targetNamespace = "http://www.openuri.org/")
    String clientRequestXML);
```

I'm passing below XML String as clientRequestXML.

```
<BODY>
        <SCODE/>
        <SMSSERVICE>
            <SENDSMS_REQ>
                <TO>
                    <CIFNUMBER>73</CIFNUMBER>
                    <MOBILE>null</MOBILE>
                    <LANG>2</LANG>
                    <MESSAGE>Dear SCUST2, your id is 1112</MESSAGE>
                </TO>
            </SENDSMS_REQ>
        </SMSSERVICE>
    </BODY>
```

please help me to solve this problem. I want to send String with comma (,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CxfProducer (in the POJO data format) expects a List. It parses the String and the comma gets interpreted as a list separator. You should pass the List as a request. For example:

```
Arrays.asList(clientRequestXML);
```